# adjusting memory alignment in a struct

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment

I am aware of the memory alignment in structure but I am stumped at this implementation I came across in a project I am working on.

```
struct default {
     uint8_t variable[((sizeof(struct dummyStructure) + 3) /4)*4]  // Align on 32 bit boundary
}
```

It is more like a black box testing for me at the moment because I dont have access to the functions, but can anyone explain the math used here to cause this alignment to happen.

Comment: What makes you think that this structure has 32-bit alignment? uint8_t data type has 1 byte alignment. And array would also have 1 byte alignment. Regardless of a size. Same for structure. On platforms I'm aware it'll have 1 byte alignment

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose it:

```
uint8_t variable[((sizeof(struct dummyStructure) + 3) /4)*4]
```

You have two cases - `sizeof dummyStructure` is evenly dividable by 4 or not.

Example:

```
(sizeof(struct dummyStructure) = 12
(12 + 3) / 4 = 15 / 4 = 3
3 * 4 = 12
```

so return original size

```
(sizeof(struct dummyStructure) = 13
(13 + 3) / 4 = 16 / 4 = 4
4 * 4 = 16
```

so return next size evenly dividable by 4

```
(sizeof(struct dummyStructure) = 15
(15 + 3) / 4 = 18 / 4 = 4
4 * 4 = 16
```

as above

```
(sizeof(struct dummyStructure) = 16
(16 + 3) / 4 = 19 / 4 = 4
4 * 4 = 16
```

so return original size again

```
(sizeof(struct dummyStructure) = 17
(17 + 3) / 4 = 20 / 4 = 5
5 * 4 = 20
```

so return next size evenly dividable by 4

In reality this code does not align variable at 32bit address! It only allocates enough space in array to allow put there dummyStructure alligned manually.
This solution is really bad.

IMHO better solutions (of course depends what happens in code):

1) since C11

```
struct defaultx
{
  alignas(4) int variable[sizeof(struct dummyStructure)];
};
```

2) gcc or clang specific

```
struct defaultx
{
  int variable[sizeof(struct dummyStructure)];
} __attribute__((aligned(4)));
```

will make sure variable is aligned to 4 bytes;

Comment: Good observation about "this code (OP's) does not align variable at 32bit address".

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that, by adding 3 to the size of dummyStructure and by taking the integer part of the result of the division by 4 to multiply by 4, you will either have:

1. The exact size of dummyStructure, if it is aligned to 32 bits (or any multiple of it, such as 64 bits).
2. Or the first multiple of 32 bits greater than the size of dummyStructure.

Therefore it will always yield a 4 bytes divisible number (32 bits alignment).

Example:

If the size of dummyStructure is 8 bytes, the result would be ((8 + 3)/4)*4 = 8.

Now if the size of dummyStructure is, lets say 11, the result would be ((11 + 3)/4)*4 = 12.

I'm just wondering why the developer decided for this, though, since dummyStructure should be always aligned according to the processor architecture.